# eloquent 5.6 model create function not found

Tags: eloquent

I am using the create function in my model extends Eloquent 5.6 Model, but I don't find this function implement in Eloquent Model, please tell me where is the source create function code?

Answer (score 0):

The `create()` method is located in [`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a4fe383b9dd2c7d2da034900f30667e8fce3365a/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L787).

Using `YourModel::create()` triggers `Model::__callStatic()` which triggers `Model::__call()`.